# Transformada de Fourier

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo csv de datos de aceleración vs tiempo y quiero hallarle la transformada de fourier de estos datos. El archivo contiene una columna de tiempo y una columna de datos de aceleración.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import fft 
import numpy as np


import pandas as pd



datosvibraciones=pd.read_csv('valores vibracion.csv' , header=0)

x = datosvibraciones[' Z (m/s2)']

t = datosvibraciones['Time (s)']
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t,x)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')


X= fft(x)   

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(abs(X))
```

Este es el resultado obtenido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debo obtener algo similar a esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Data:

```
Time (s), Z (m/s2)
397.0999756,9.885103
397.1100159,9.139797
397.1200562,9.139797
397.1300354,9.80665
397.1399841,10.473502
397.1500244,8.433719
397.1599731,8.904438
397.1700439,9.728196
397.1801453,7.649187
397.1900024,10.120462
397.1999817,10.473502
397.2101135,7.84532
397.2200317,9.45361
397.230011,8.629851
397.2399902,9.728196
397.25,10.002783
397.2600403,9.68897
397.2700195,10.355823
397.2799988,9.532063
397.2900085,9.92433
397.3000488,9.218251
397.3100281,9.57129
397.3199768,10.787314
397.3300476,9.296704
397.3399658,9.532063
397.3500671,8.669079
397.3599854,8.159133
397.3699951,9.257478
397.3799744,8.825985
397.3899841,8.982891
397.4000244,9.92433
397.4100037,9.296704
397.4199829,9.179024
397.4300232,9.492837
397.440033,9.649743
397.4500427,10.081236
397.4599915,9.649743
397.4700317,8.865211
397.4799805,8.316039
397.4900513,8.943665
397.5,9.061344
397.5100403,8.041452
397.519989,9.57129
397.5299988,8.159133
397.5400085,8.708305
397.5499878,10.081236
397.5599976,8.943665
397.5700378,9.335931
397.5800171,9.80665
397.5899963,9.061344
397.5999756,9.335931
397.6100159,9.296704
397.6200256,8.276813
397.6300354,8.237586
397.6399841,10.395049
397.6500549,9.414384
397.6600037,8.041452
397.6700439,9.68897
397.6799927,8.982891
397.6900024,10.198915
397.6999817,8.551398
397.7099915,9.414384
397.7200012,8.119906
397.7299805,9.80665
397.7399902,9.845877
397.7499695,8.865211
397.7600708,9.218251
397.769989,10.081236
397.7799683,9.061344
397.7900085,10.120462
397.8000793,9.100571
397.8100586,9.610517
397.8199768,9.532063
397.8300476,8.825985
397.8399658,8.825985
397.8500366,8.198359
397.8600159,10.002783
397.8699951,8.629851
397.8799744,8.943665
397.8899841,9.80665
397.9000244,10.002783
397.9100037,8.982891
397.9200134,9.335931
397.9299927,9.963556
397.940033,9.963556
397.9499817,11.101128
397.960022,8.904438
397.9700012,7.296147
397.9800415,8.904438
397.9900208,9.296704
398,8.159133
398.0100403,9.375157
398.019989,10.238142
398.0299988,8.316039
398.0400085,10.198915
398.0499878,9.100571
398.0600281,8.512172
398.0699768,9.728196
398.0800171,8.982891
398.0899963,8.002226
398.1000061,8.159133
398.1100159,9.845877
398.1199951,7.963
398.1300354,9.45361
398.1400146,10.002783
398.1499939,9.257478
398.1600342,10.002783
398.1700439,9.532063
398.1800232,8.629851
398.1900024,9.532063
398.2000122,9.414384
```

Comment: Seria genial que muestres lo que has intentado y señalar en que parte te has quedado atascado.

Comment: El código lo he colocado en la pregunta ahora mismo

Comment: okay, ¿cual es el problema con ese código?

Comment: cuando grafico la transformada de fourier me muestra que la frecuencia es 0Hz, lo cual no me sirve porque es una vibración.

Comment: seria genial que proveas un [MRE], por ejemplo compartir una parte de tu data, una imagen de lo que obtienes y de lo que deberias obtener para entender mejor tu problema. Te recomiendo leer [ask] y pasar el [tour]

Comment: Añadí algunas imagenes, no sé como usar los parametros de la funcion fft para que utilice mi data, es probable que ese sea el principal problema

Comment: te falta compartir el .csv, es lo más importante.

Comment: no conozco la forma de adjuntarlo. como lo hago?

Comment: por ejemplo copia 100 filas y pegalos en tu pregunta

Comment: He puesto una parte del data

Answer (score 0):

Con los datos que has pasado, en realidad no sale 0 la frecuencia, lo que pasa es que el primer valor es tan elevado que así lo parece en la gráfica.

Añadiendo alguna línea para eliminar el primer valor y ver qué está pasando:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import fft 
import numpy as np

datosvibraciones=pd.read_csv('valores vibracion.csv' , header=0)

x = datosvibraciones[' Z (m/s2)']

t = datosvibraciones['Time (s)']
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t,x)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')

X= fft(x) 

new_X = np.delete(X, 0)
print(type(X))

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(abs(new_X))

plt.show()
```

Sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si ese puede ser el problema...